# grpcAuthenticationReader error whenever trying to start my server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

I just integerated a GRPC server to my user application but whenever I try to start my application I am getting the following error. I am not able to find the proper logs regarding this error as not much information is available online.

```
Description:

Parameter 1 of method authenticatingServerInterceptor in net.devh.boot.grpc.server.autoconfigure.GrpcServerSecurityAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'net.devh.boot.grpc.server.security.authentication.GrpcAuthenticationReader' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'net.devh.boot.grpc.server.security.authentication.GrpcAuthenticationReader' in your configuration.
```

The error posted has been **solved** and it can be found in the answers below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution just needed to add:

```
  @Bean
  public  GrpcAuthenticationReader grpcAuthenticationReader(){
    return new BasicGrpcAuthenticationReader();
  }
```

in my SpringSecurityConfig file.

Referenced from here:https://yidongnan.github.io/grpc-spring-boot-starter/en/server/security.html